# Will a DBCC CHECKDB with repair have to rescan?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, dbcc-checkdb

I've run a `DBCC CHECKDB` and it found allocation errors. When I run it with `REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS` - will it need to take the same amount of time to scan for errors, or will it attempt to use the last `CHECKDB` I ran and go faster?

(SQL Server 2000.  Yes its ancient, no I can't upgrade.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> will it need to take the same amount of time to scan for errors

Yes it has to do it again .. scan **and** fix the errors **with potential data loss**. Be cautious, use it as a last resort - repair & allow data loss !

Refer : [Corruption .. Last resorts that people try first…](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/corruption-last-resorts-that-people-try-first/) from Paul Randal.

Remember : SQL Server 2000 is out of support .. so microsoft is not going to help unless you upgrade to a supported version !

Answer (score 6):

To add to the answer above, if you're on Enterprise Edition, where a normal DBCC CHECKDB will run in parallel, when you run with a repair option it must run single-thread, so it will also take more time.

Any DBCC CHECK* command has to scan all the data as the results from any previous DBCC CHECK* command are

1. not persisted anywhere
2. in no way can be trusted to still be accurate.

Also be wary of REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS on SQL Server 2000 - there are many repairs that do not work correctly, that I fixed for SQL Server 2005 as part of my general rewrite of the code base.

Thanks